# Query em SQL/Firebird agrupando um somatório por natureza

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-2.5

Estou tentando fazer uma **Query** na tabela de produtos para me retornar a seguinte informação abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer de uma forma agrupada totalizando os valores. Existe uma **coluna** com nome **natureza**, que tem o lançamento **à crédito** representado por **'C'** e **débito** representado por **'D'**. Que no final eu gostaria que ficasse em uma unica coluna, conforme imagem acima.

A caluna valor recebe os lacamentos da natureza **'C'** menos **'D'** e gostaria que a coluna resultado mostrasse se o resultado é **positivo** ou **negativo.**

***Tenho que agrupar por grupo e valor***

Tenho a **Query** abaixo, mas não consegui evoluir

```
SELECT
CC.CODIGO_PRODUTO AS PRODUTO,
GS.GRUPO AS GRUPO,
GS.CODIGO_GRUPO AS NOME_GRUPO,
CC.TIPO_NATUREZA AS NATUREZA,
CC.VALOR
FROM LANCAMENTOS CC
INNER JOIN GRUPO GS ON GS.CODIGO_GRUPO = CC.CODIGO_GRUPO
```

Que resulta nessas informações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como consigo evoluir a **query**? Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a construção CASE / WHEN na função de agregação:

```
SELECT
CC.CODIGO_PRODUTO AS PRODUTO,
GS.GRUPO AS GRUPO,
GS.CODIGO_GRUPO AS NOME_GRUPO,
SUM( CASE CC.TIPO_NATUREZA
    WHEN "C" THEN CC.VALOR
    WHEN "D" THEN -1*CC.VALOR END) AS TOTAL
FROM LANCAMENTOS CC
INNER JOIN GRUPO GS ON GS.CODIGO_GRUPO = CC.CODIGO_GRUPO
GROUP BY PRODUTO, GRUPO, NOME_GRUPO;
```

Comment: Estou tentando Rodar a SQL, mas está dando erro. 

Aparece esse erro :

Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 7, column 31.
).

nessa linha  WHEN 'D' THEN -1*CC.VALOR ) AS TOTAL

Comment: Consegui, coloquei o END do CASE. Ficando assim:  WHEN 'D' THEN -1*CC.VALOR END ) AS TOTAL

Comment: Isto, faltou o END. Vou corrigir a resposta.